# Deserializing packed bytes to a Stream member with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, .net, memory, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Is there a way to deserialize a `bytes` field to a Stream member, without protobuf-net allocating a new (and potentially big) byte[] upfront?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Message
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    Stream Payload { get; set; }
}
```

Where the Stream could be backed by a pre-allocated buffer pool e.g. `Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream`. Even after dropping down to `ProtoReader` for deserialization all I see is `AppendBytes`, which always allocates a buffer of field length. One has to drop even further to `DirectReadBytes`, which only operates directly on the message stream -- I'd like to avoid that.

As background, I'm using protobuf-net to serialize/deserialize messages across the wire. This is a middle-layer component for passing messages between clients, so the messages are really an envelope for an enclosed binary payload:

```
message Envelope {
  required string messageId = 1;
  map<string, string> headers = 2;
  bytes payload = 3;
}
```

The size of `payload` is restricted to ~2 MB, but large enough for the byte[] to land in the LOH.

Using a surrogate as in [Protobuf-net: Serializing a 3rd party class with a Stream data member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327277/protobuf-net-serializing-a-3rd-party-class-with-a-stream-data-member/17334206#17334206) doesn't work because it simply wraps the same monolithic array.

One technique that should work is mentioned in [Memory usage serializing chunked byte arrays with Protobuf-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317045/memory-usage-serializing-chunked-byte-arrays-with-protobuf-net), changing `bytes` to `repeated bytes` and relying on the sender to limit each chunk. This solution may be good enough, it'll prevent LOH allocation, but it won't allow buffer pooling.

Comment: Not in c#.  Serialization requires entire data to be in an object for standard serialization to work.  You could write a custom serializer, or write code in c++.

Comment: C# itself shouldn't be an issue, I can definitely do it with custom serialization by reading a chunk from the message stream and writing to the payload-field stream. On the other hand, I was hoping to leverage the excellent protobuf-net library as much as possible.

Comment: Why can't you wait for the entire buffer to be received before serialization?

Comment: I'm fine with receiving the entire message, as it is buffered in a stream that  divides it amongst small byte[], what I wanted to avoid was protobuf-net's allocation of a monolithic byte[] for one of the blob fields in the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question here is about the `payload` field. No, there is not current a mechanism to handle that, but it is certainly something that could be investigated for options. It could be that we can do something like an `ArraySegment<byte> AllocateBuffer(int size)` callback on the serialization-context that the caller could use to take control of the allocations (the nice thing about this is that protobuf-net doesn't actually work with `ArraySegment<byte>`, so it would be a purely incremental change that wouldn't impact any existing working code; if no callback is provided, we would presumably just allocate a flat buffer like it does currently). I'm open to other suggestions, but right now: no - it will allocate a `byte[]` internally.

Comment: I think your proposal would work Marc. The ArraySegments would be handed out from a LOH-allocated pool and returned when the wrapping type is disposed.

Comment: wondering if this is supported yet? I too have similar question on this.

Comment: @Rohit it isn't something I've looked into, and Stream is especially problematic (for deserialization, knowing which to choose, rewinding, etc); however, with the 3.0 bits, it would probably be quite easy to support `Memory<byte>` or `ReadOnlySequence<byte>` - in fact I have some examples of that using custom allocators, for example the "arenas" allocator from another of my libraries. Any use?

Comment: Yes Memory<T> would be lovely